# If emacsclient already open, new emacsclient should "inherit" its buffer list

Tags: frames, emacsclient, emacs-daemon

My workflow involves splitting frames a lot because I use i3wm. If I use the emacs native `make-frame-command`, the new frame will be visiting the buffer I invoked the command in. If I call `emacsclient` from a shell/keyboard short cut however, it default-visits the `*scratch*` buffer.

I'd like  `emacsclient` to replicate the behaviour of `make-frame-command`. Is this possible?

Comment: All clients of a given server see the same buffer list (because the buffer list is a part of the server, not a part of the client), so your title doesn't make sense. Perhaps you could amend it?

Comment: Hence the quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
emacsclient -e '(make-frame-command)'
```

If I do

```
emacsclient -e '(make-frame-command)' -t
```

it opens in a TTY instead of a new GUI frame, but then I have to do 'C-x 5 0' twice to get it to close...

Comment: That's close to perfect for my needs, I always run in GUI mode anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This hack works best for me

```
emacsclient -cne '(lambda () (interactive) previous-buffer)'
```

since emacs is dead set on switching buffers.